# Android - Can I force a call to View.onSizeChanged when starting an activity from another activity

Tags: java, android, view, android-activity

I have an activity that is basically just a splash screen. A button in this activity starts a new activity which has a view in it that depends on the `View.onSizeChanged` callback to setup critical resources, (it needs the size values to set up a grid of tiles).

The first time i run the app, everything works fine. The `onSizeChanged` callback is called at some point after the view is created, and the tile grid gets set up correctly. If I then hit the back button, (which takes me back to the splash screen activity and cleans up/destroys the other activity), things are still ok. From the splash screen, (without exiting the app altogether), if I then click the start button again, I get a null pointer exception when the first tile is trying to be set, (because the grid is null, because `View.onSizeChanged` was not called).

Is there a way to, or is it even appropriate to, force a guaranteed call to `View.onSizeChanged` every time the second activity is started, and hence the view needing it is created?

Does this make enough sense without posting the code?

Comment: @MukRaker: I'd say you probably need to post code even if it's just an outline of methods with comments indicating what you are doing and where/when in the code. I suspect (but may be wrong) that you may be doing stuff in the 2nd Activity in onCreate() when it may be better placed in onResume().

Comment: Ah... that sounds like it may be my problem. I'm going to try a few things and if I'm still stuck, I'll post some code. Thanks! However, isn't onCreate called each time the activity is started?

Comment: @MukRaker: onCreate is called each time the Activity is created (urrm obviously) but that isn't necessarily the same as 'started'. In many/most cases, using the BACK button to finish an Activity will take it through the full pause/stop/destroy steps but that may not always be the case. If it hasn't been fully destroyed then next time it's 'entered' (for want of a better word), it may not do so at the 'create' stage and may simply go through a restart/start stage or even go back in at the 'resume' stage.

Comment: I am sure it is getting destroyed, and I am not persisting anything, so I am not clear on how something is getting saved/cached between onDestroy, and the next onCreate. At least that is what it seems like is happening. I would think the next tiem the activity is started, ti would go through the same processing as it does any other time. I even put code in this time to finish the parent activity when the child activity finishes, and still when I run the app a second time, I get the error from the child activity.

Comment: @MukRaker: You may well be right and the Activity IS getting destroyed but unless you trace it, it's hard to be 100% sure. Either way, you're clearly doing something the first time around which isn't being repeated the second time.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured it out. I was doing a few things ultimately during onCreate that should have happened after onCreate was done. It's working now!

Comment: @MukRaker: Good to hear. Have fun.